# Query terrible slow after DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS / FREEPROCCACHE

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a complex query that runs under 2 seconds (which is ok), however if i run

```
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS 
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
```

first the query performans goes oder 40 seconds. Should I be worried?

Comment: you appear to be questioning why flushing everything out of memory makes your query slower. that would be because data has to be read from storage....

Comment: Try only DBCC FREEPROCCACHE or with RECOMPILE. If it takes 40 sec to run this means that query compile time is 38 sec. You should be worried.

Comment: 38 sec is not necessarily just compilation time. SQL Server stores data in cache (RAM) memory which helps with query execution time. You should not be worried, you just should not execute these two dbcc statements

Comment: "Doctor, it hurts when I do this". "Don't do that then."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Sql server is doing ***EXACTLY*** what you just told it to. You asked it to empty out ALL it's hard earned buffers.

It ran first previously because it had stored the information about the tables and the query in the caches and deleted the execution plans. Having purged them it has to rebuild them from scratch.

**Don't do that unless you've a good reason to.**

*Use DBCC FREEPROCCACHE to clear the plan cache carefully. Freeing the plan cache causes, for example, a stored procedure to be recompiled instead of reused from the cache. This can cause a sudden, temporary decrease in query performance. For each cleared cachestore in the plan cache, the SQL Server error log will contain the following informational message: "SQL Server has encountered %d occurrence(s) of cachestore flush for the ‘%s’ cachestore (part of plan cache) due to ‘DBCC FREEPROCCACHE’ or ‘DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE’ operations." This message is logged every five minutes as long as the cache is flushed within that time interval.*

*Use DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS to test queries with a cold buffer cache without shutting down and restarting the server.
To drop clean buffers from the buffer pool, first use CHECKPOINT to produce a cold buffer cache. This forces all dirty pages for the current database to be written to disk and cleans the buffers. After you do this, you can issue DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS command to remove all buffers from the buffer pool.*

Comment: On modern systems ' DBCC FREEPROCCACHE ' is no longer such a scary command.